# Backup laptop and server folder using rsync

Tags: backup, rsync

I want to have a folder in my laptop synched in the server. My purpose is to have 'cloned' folder in laptop and server. Both folders will be updated when changing files either in laptop or server with rsync. Would be great if you could give me some hints about the rsync command to do this.

Maybe this would work:

```
# from laptop to server. 
rsync -av /Volumes/NewHDD1_DATA/Projects_archive_Small bernardo@128.139.17.11:/home/bernardo/Projects_archive_Small
# from server to laptop
rsync -av /home/bernardo/Projects_archive_Small/Projects_archive_Small bernardo@dhcp17-207.agri.huji.ac.il:/Volumes/NewHDD1_DATA/
```

I also would like to remove old files no longer existing in local or remote.
There's maybe a better alternative to rsync.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, consider putting the folder under version control with SVN (if it's a lot of binary files, I recommend against Git).  SVN has a lot of advantages over rsync and a few downsides:

- SVN handles binary files very well, sending only compressed deltas across the wire
- Everything is versioned, so accidental deletes can be undone
- Very efficient across the wire and in server-side storage

Downsides:

- There is no purge / permanent delete command, so once files are in SVN, they are permanent unless you dump/load the backend database
- Git has better branch/merge support (which is generally not needed for documents)

Answer (score 0):

Syntax is correct, you can add "--delete" to remove what's is not wanted anymore.
Best choice for making this cool : make 2 scripts (from-remote-to-local and from-local-to-remote), on each machine.If you use periodic updates like in a crontab, you might sync with unwanted data, so, be careful with that ;-)
You can also setup an 'rsync' daemon on a third location, that will be your reference target (it could be on one of the hosts, by the way).